# Mapping Map with an Entity as a key in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, orm, mapping

Is it possible to map:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = Array(CascadeType.ALL), fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
Map<Entity, Double> quantities;
```

instead of:

```
Map<Double, Entity>
```

?

If not, how do you map for example Item quantities in a shop basket (without dedicated table)?

Thanks in advance,
Etam.

Answer (score 2):

You can using an @ElementCollection and a @MapKeyJoinColumn,

see
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Map_Key_Columns_.28JPA_2.0.29

But it is kind of an unusual model, you may be better off create an Entity to map to the join table instead.

Comment: Why would one be better off creating an Entity? For instance in this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327752/hibernate-mapping-many-to-many-to-map/4328788#4328788

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be mapped without additional entity, see, for example, [Hibernate: mapping many-to-many to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327752/hibernate-mapping-many-to-many-to-map/4328788#4328788).

Also note that dedicated table will be used anyway, it just can be mapped as an entity, or not.