# How to create relationships in JPA that contains attributes?

Tags: jpa

I need to put an attribute in a relation of a JSF / JPA project.

Example:

Table Person:

**Id - Name**

1 - Carl

2 - John

3 - Jess

Music Table:

**Id - Music**

10 - Satisfaction

15 - Imagine

20 - Bohemian Rhapsody

*How should the Relationship Table*:

**Id - IdPerson - IdMusic - Liked**

30 - __1__  - ____10____ - Yes

31 - __2__ - ____15____ - No

32 - __3__ - ____20____ - Yes

How to create relationships in JPA that contains attributes?

Comment: Simply enough, you need to model the relationship as yet another entity. Alternatively, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325059/mapping-map-with-an-entity-as-a-key-in-jpa) for a different approach

Comment: Hi @crizzis, thank you for your response. You say something like this: [link](https://giannigar.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/mapping-a-many-to-many-join-table-with-extra-column-using-jpa/).
Would it be an entity and assign them composite keys?

Comment: Using an [`EmbeddedId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html) is probably more convenient, but that's the general idea

Comment: I made that [example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/) with @AssociationOverride, it's solving.